# How to override checkout on module enable/disable in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to override this by enabling/disable the module from admin.

```
<item name="progressBar" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
  <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/progress-bar</item>
</item>
```

Please let me know thanks.

Comment: please explain your question properly? What is your want disabled .want to  disable the Progress bar

Comment: @AmitBera  Actually, I want to override any js file from making a module. But It will depend on module disable/enable from admin option.  So If module is disabled then only default js render and if enabled then module js rendered.

Comment: @AmitBera  here is admin option https://prnt.sc/tw3koj

Comment: Why you don't try this._super() if your module is disabled?

Comment: @AmitBera Actually, I did not know, so can you explain me in detail please.

Comment: @SohelRana   Okay, Actually I am trying to create a new checkout module to I need to override some js, right? but  I have to add that functionality when module id enable from admin as I was given the option to admin enable/disable. So if enable then custom module js is rendered and if disable then default js render.

Comment: @SohelRana Any update?